# Reinstalling CKEditor module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I installed the latest recommanded release of CKEditor, but when I tried to change content authoring I got an error saying it wasn't installed properly.

So I tried uninstalling it by doing:

- disable module ckeditor
- uninstall
- tried to look for the    module in my project and    delete there
  also (site/all/modules) but it isn't present

When I trie to reinstall (dev version) I get:

- Archivers can only operate on local files:
  temporary://update-cache-235f2e3c/ckeditor-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz not
  supported
  and then when I trie the same link a second time:
- CKEditor is already installed.

Also clearing the cache in development doesn't work.
How can I properly delete and reinstall ckeditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable the Module
2. Uninstall the Module
3. Delete the Module folder from sites/all/modules
4. Remove the CkEditor folder from site/all/libraries
5. Clear the Cache
6. Copy the CkEditor Module to site/all/modules folder
7. Copy the [Downloaded CkEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) to sites/all/libraries folder
8. If in *nix systems, check the folder permissions. (Most of the time this happens to be the issue)
9. Enable the Module as usual.

More info is given [CkEditor docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Installation)